# $http.get doesn't load JSON

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I can't load my `JSON` file. There is no error. I'm stuck, any suggestions?

app.js:

```
app.controller('StoreController',['$http','$scope', function($http,$scope) {

    $http.get("data.json").success(function(response) {
        $scope.names = response;
    });

}]);
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app= "App">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">

<div ng-repeat="item in names" style="border: solid 1px black; margin: 10px auto; padding: 5px; width: 500px;"  >

   <h3>{{item.Name}}    </h3>

   <p>{{item.Country}}</p>

</div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Nothing is showing. What should I do?

Comment: Did you see what network says?

Comment: Are you running this on a server or just accessing local file system?

Comment: I'm running it on localhost.and its blank and nothing is showing

Comment: Check your network activity in your browsers dev tools.

Comment: Its probably because you didn't assign an `ng-controller="StoreController"` in your index?

Comment: i put it in `<body ng-controller="StoreController>` tag.but nothing happens

Comment: In Network activity ,there are four `304 Not Modified status`.what should i do?

Comment: Is the `success` being called? With what 'response' `console.log('response = '+angular.toJson(response))`.
Add a .error to the `get` to see if the the promise is rejected. You can dump out the status code from there.

Comment: The console give this error,line 4 in `app.js` is `$http({method:'GET', url:'/data.json'}).success(function(response,status){
 $scope.names = response;
 console.log('response = '+angular.toJson(response));
 }).error(function(error,status){
 });`The Error is here `TypeError: object is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Angular/app.js:4:3)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js:34:483)`, i'm confuseeed

Answer (score 1):

Have you register your module app in app.js?

var app = angular.module('App', []);

Comment: i didn't put the rest of code here which are not necessary..yes i named it to: `var app = angular.module('App', []);` .

Comment: Ok. Then issue may be deploying it on http server, your data.json file on same folder level or on another folder.
Please try with
 $http({url:'data.json').success(function(response,status){$scope.names = response;}).error(function(error,status){});

Comment: As per your error file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/Angular/app.js:4:3 on, I think you are accessing $http method on local system not on server. You can put your project in Apache Tomcat webapps folder and start the server and access the page on http://localhost:8080//{your_app_name}}. It may work.