# JSON doesn't load using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have the same problem as the guy in this topic:
[$http.get doesn't load JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25450063/http-get-doesnt-load-json)

Can't find the solution either way.
I run the website using MAMP, so that isn't the problem i guess?

Here is the code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="myQuiz">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Test Your Knowledge: Saturn</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quiz.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" ng-src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" ng-src="js/quiz.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myQuiz" ng-controller="QuizController">
            <h1>Test Your Knowledge: <span> Saturn</span></h1>
            <div class="progress">
                {{totalQuestions}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

quiz.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myQuiz', []);

    app.controller('QuizController', ['$scope','$http','$sce',function($scope,$http, $sce){

        $scope.score = 0;
        $scope.activeQuestion = -1;
        $scope.activeQuestionAnswered = 0;
        $scope.percentage = 0;

        $http.get('quiz_data.json').then(function(quizData){
            $scope.myQuestions = quizData.data;
            $scope.totalQuestions = $scope.myQuestions.length;
        });
    }]);
})();
```

quiz_data.json

```
[
    {
        "question" : "Saturn is the _______ planet from the Sun.",
        "answers" : [
            { "id" : 0, "text" : "Fourth" },
            { "id" : 1, "text" : "Sixth" },
            { "id" : 2, "text" : "Second" },
            { "id" : 3, "text" : "Eighth" }
        ],
        "correct" : 1
    },
        {
        "question" : "Which image shows a close-up of Saturn?",
        "answers"  : [
            {"id"  : 0, "image" : "images/close_up_01.jpg" },
            {"id"  : 1, "image" : "images/close_up_02.jpg" },
            {"id"  : 2, "image" : "images/close_up_03.jpg" },
            {"id"  : 3, "image" : "images/close_up_04.jpg" }
        ],
        "correct"  : 3
    },
    {
        "question" : "One year on Saturn is equivalent to how many years on Earth?",
        "answers"  : [
            {"id"  : 0, "text" : "12"},
            {"id"  : 1, "text" : "6"},
            {"id"  : 2, "text" : "29"},
            {"id"  : 3, "text" : "2"}
        ],
        "correct"  : 2
    },
    {
        "question" : "What is the name of Saturn's largest moon?",
        "answers"  : [
            {"id"  : 0, "text" : "Hercules"},
            {"id"  : 1, "text" : "Europa"},
            {"id"  : 2, "text" : "Goliath"},
            {"id"  : 3, "text" : "Zeus"},
            {"id"  : 4, "text" : "Titan"},
            {"id"  : 5, "text" : "Triton"}
        ],
        "correct"  : 4,
        "feedback" : "Though the names seem similar, Triton orbits the planet Neptune."
    },
    {
        "question" : "Saturn is visible from Earth without a telescope",
        "answers"  : [
            {"id"  : 0, "text" : "True"},
            {"id"  : 1, "text" : "False"}
        ],
        "correct"  : 0
    }
]
```

[website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYvyF.jpg)
It looks like the connection with json doesn't work. Don't know how to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like nothings being rendered at all. What does the console say?

Comment: don't use `ng-src` while loading java-script references. instead it should use `src` attribute only like `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/quiz.js"></script>`, I don't think so that will fix any problem but saw that and commented. Is there any error in console?

Comment: This is the error:
angular.min.js:87 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/MAMP/htdocs/S3/portfolio_v2/quiz_data.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: Install a localhost server on your computer. Can't make ajax requests from `file://` protocol due to browser security restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to go to your file through the local http server.

From the `website` image, it looks like you are loading your index.html through the file system and not through your web server.

Your address bar should be `http://localhost:8888/<path to your index.html>` or whatever port your web server is running on.

Comment: Don't know for sure if i did it correctly, but i run the line 'npm install http-server -g' in cmd. After that i went to http://localhost:8080/index.html where they asked for a username and password. But is don't know them, where can i find it? Don't know if i missed some steps to install either.

Comment: I edited my answer about starting/installing a local http server. I didn't realize that you were already using MAMP. Going by their documentation at https://documentation.mamp.info/en/documentation/mamp/, I guess once you start the server, you can visit your page at `http://localhost:8888/S3/portfolio_v2/index.html`